# How to access the lower manual and pedalboard on setBfree Organ emulator

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, organ, virtual-instrument

**I installed the organ emulator `setBfree` on a Debian GNU/Linux System.**

[image: setBfree Organ emulator GUI]

I run it with Jack connected to the simple USB MIDI controller keyboard. This is working fairly well to connect to the *upper manual*. Though I cannot figure out how to get a connection to the *lower manual* and *pedalboard*.

[image: jack connection to setbfree organ]

As one can see in the picture, there is only one MIDI input for the instrument. **Does anyone know how I can control the other two keyboards? Do I need some CC control programming for this?** *(There does not seem to be any option relating to this issue in the GUI preferences)*

Comment: "Manual" comes from the Latin word for "hand," so it's not correct to call the pedalboard a "manual."  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [reference](https://linuxmao.org/forumthread62181) (sorry in French), the other manuals can be accessed by changing the MIDI channel.

The link actually gives a technique, using qmidiroute (a very useful program), to map different part of a midi keyboard to the different register.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I was just having a look for `qmidiroute` THX hinting in this direction again! For now I came up with a simple and not quite satisfying workaround - since the overlapping of notes -> https://music.stackexchange.com/a/129677/42816 You have been 13 Seconds faster ;-)

Comment: @nath Your answer is more complete but if I had took the time to mention a2j I would have lost this race ;)

Answer (score 2):

**I found the answer, pretty simple:**

```
Parameters for 'MIDI Parser':
  midi.upper.channel                         I  (1)
    The MIDI channel to use for the upper manual. range: [1..16]
  midi.lower.channel                         I  (2)
    The MIDI channel to use for the lower manual. range: [1..16]
  midi.pedals.channel                        I  (3)
    The MIDI channel to use for the pedals. range: [1..16]
```

Manual 1 uses Channel 1
Manual 2 uses Channel 2
Pedalboard uses Channel 3

Since my simple controller keyboard has no facility to change the channel, I installed the virtual `jack keyboard` where I can set the desired channel and switched it in between the organ input and MIDI keyboard output:

[image: jack-keyboard channel 1]
[image: jack-keyboard channel 3]

Unfortunately `jack keyboard` can not split the keyboard. I worked around it by starting two instances of it, one using MIDI channel 1 and the other one using MIDI channel 3. There is some overlapping unfortunately but like this I can play the pedalboard with the low keys and the upper manual with the higher keys. *(HuaXing is the output of my hardware controller keyboard):*

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** inspired by [--> Toms answer <--](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/129676/42816)

with the application `qmidiroute` — a MIDI event processor and router — the organ manuals can be accessed in any way that is within the range of the hardware keyboard. Since `qmidiroute` does not supply jack ports it needs to be combined with the *ALSA to JACK MIDI bridge* `a2jmidi_bridge`.

Here is an example using the two low octaves of the controller keyboard for the foot-pedal and the the higher octaves for the upper manual *(since it is a small keyboard the low octave of the upper manual is skipped):*

[image: qmidiroute foot-pedal]

---

[image: qmidiroute upper-manual]

---

*(HuaXing again, is the output of my hardware controller keyboard):*

[image: jack connections]

Comment: Is it really called the "food pedal"? If yes, my edit to the initial question needs to be rolled back. Otherwise, this post needs an edit.

Comment: @Aaron Not quite sure :-/ THX for asking. *Upper manual*, *lower manual*, *pedals*...? Did not read about the "food" anywhere - that is how I call it. If it is wrong we can take it out and call it just *pedals*. Though its played with the food I think it can not be too much of big fault ;-)

Comment: Okay, I think you've just confused the words "food" (a thing that is eaten) and "foot" (the body part a shoe goes on). "Foot pedal" is the term you want.

Comment: @Aaron Cheers <3 <3 <3 (No native speaker) :-))))

Comment: "pedal" comes from the Latin word for "foot," so "foot pedal" is redundant.  I've edited accordingly along with some other corrections.